# Count numerical values in each column in R

Tags: r, counter, numeric

I would like to count the numeric values in each collumn in my data frame (all):

```
NE001710    NE001360    NE001398    NE001380    NE001707
-0.12        -0.61       -0.61        -0.02       0.13
-0.58        -0.43       -0.24        -0.27      -0.47
  NA          0.19       -0.37        -0.14      -0.53
  NA         -0.13       -0.27        -0.38       0.05
  NA          NA          0.32        -0.34       0.01
```

The expected output can be something like that: `res <- c("2","4","5","5","5")`

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you already know that all of your columns contain only numeric data and `NA` values, then you really just want to count the number of non-`NA` values, which can easily be done like this:

```
colSums(!is.na(all))
# NE001710 NE001360 NE001398 NE001380 NE001707 
#        2        4        5        5        5
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
## sapply(all, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))
vapply(all, function(x) length(na.omit(x)), 1L)
# NE001710 NE001360 NE001398 NE001380 NE001707 
#        2        4        5        5        5
```

Comment: This is not quite universal -- what if some of his columns are factors or characters?  To be "extra safe" , I'd throw in a `is.na(all) & is.numeric(all)` thingy.  I'll grant the OP only presented an example containing numerics (presumably) and `NA` values.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, hence my first sentence stating the assumptions of my answer. I am only working with what I've been given!